# Filtering product collection by combination of attributes

Tags: collection-filtering

I have two sets of product attributes:

```
Att1 {a, b, c, d}
Att2 {e, f, g, h}
```

These attributes are multiple select fields.

Then I have a collection of 3 products:

```
Prod1 (Att1: {b, d, a}, Att2: {g})
Prod2 (Att1: {a, c},    Att2: {h, f})
Prod3 (Att1: {a, d},    Att2: {e, f, g})
```

From this collection I'd like to extract product with these attribute combination

`Att1 LIKE 'a, d' AND Att2 LIKE 'g'`

so that the result would be Prod1 and Prod3

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter
```

accepts only one attribute but I'd like to add a combinaiton of two.

How can I do this?